# Linux: How to get a machine's IP address?

Tags: linux, ip, scripting

I'm using Linux CentOS 6.4 .

I'm writing a shell script and I need to extract a machine's IP in order to use it in the script.
How can I find the machine's IP?

I'm looking for the "best" way because I know there are a few ways to get IP addresses.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are ways to get your Linux machine IP address:

```
/sbin/ifconfig
```

If you know the name of your Network Interface card, you can specify it in the command and get the results for that specific NIC:

```
/sbin/ifconfig eth0
```

Another command is:

```
/sbin/ip addr
```

If you know the name of your Network Interface card, you can specify it in the command and get the results for that specific NIC:

```
/sbin/ip addr show eth0
```

I think this is the best way:

```
hostname -i
```

Bare in mind that in some servers you might have more than one Network Interfacr Cards...

Comment: That was quick! thank you! I think I'll use the `hostname -i` one.

Comment: use of hostname -i is discouraged in the manpage:

Display the network address(es) of the host  name.  Note  that  this works  only  if  the  host  name  can  be resolved. Avoid using this option; use hostname --all-ip-addresses instead.

Comment: In case your machine is behind a router and you need your public IP you can use this service: `curl ifconfig.me`

Answer (score 0):

I'd use facter for that.

```
yum install facter
facter ipaddress
facter ipaddress_eth0
```

Comment: Isn't facter related to Puppet or something like that?

Comment: yes it comes from the puppet ecosystem, but works perfectly fine as standalone application.

Comment: Facter is related to Puppet, yes, but you can use Facter without Puppet (though not the other way around).